# VS 2010 Intellisense Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a C# library class which is being consumed by an ASP.NET 4.0 Web Forms application. In my class, I'm trying to access the HttpRequest.Application object as described here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx

This documentation says it is in the System.Web namespace but even when I add a reference in my library project, it is still not available to me.

The only way I can get to the ApplicationPath property is by using:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath;
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ApplicationPath` is not a static property on `HttpRequest`, which is why you have to access it using the instance `HttpContext.Current.Request`. If you don't want to use `HttpContext.Current.Request` you could always pass the `HttpRequest` object in to your class library from your ASP.NET web forms.

For example (from your Page_Load):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myClass = new MyClass();
    myClass.MyMethod(this.Request);
}
```